# Wordpress gallery function returns nothing while echo does

Tags: php, wordpress

The custom *my_post_gallery* function for a *post_gallery* hook doesn't return the images, when the amount of images in one post is somewhere near 60. It cannot be specified more precisely because it varies from case to case. That alone is odd.

*echo* returns the images in any case.

Helper Functions seem to work correctly.

I suspect a php.ini or apache problem?

```html
function my_post_gallery($output, $attr) {
 global $post;
 
 if (isset($attr['orderby'])) {
  $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby($attr['orderby']);
  if (!$attr['orderby'])
   unset($attr['orderby']);
 }

 extract(shortcode_atts(array(
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
  'id' => $post->ID,
  'itemtag' => 'dl',
  'icontag' => 'dt',
  'captiontag' => 'dd',
  'columns' => '3',
  'size' => 'thumbnail',
  'include' => '',
  'exclude' => ''
 ), $attr));
 
 $id = intval($id);
 if ('RAND' == $order) $orderby = 'none';
 
 if (!empty($include)) {
  $include = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include);
  $_attachments = get_posts(array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby));
  
  $attachments = array();
  foreach ($_attachments as $key => $val) {
   $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
  }
 }
 
 
 if (empty($attachments)) return '';
 
 $output = "<div class=\"wrapper-gallery\">\n";
 
 foreach ($attachments as $id => $attachment) {
  $img = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($id);
  if ($columns == '3') { $url = $img['sizes']['medium']['url']; };
  if ($columns == '2') { $url = $img['sizes']['large']['url']; };
  if ($columns == '1') { $url = $img['sizes']['large']['url']; };
  $alt = $img['title'];
  $posturl = urlencode(get_permalink());
  ob_start();
  the_subtitle();
  $subtitle = ob_get_clean();
  $pinalt = get_the_title() . ' - ' . $subtitle;
  
  $altreplace = '$2';
  $altneu = $url;
  $altneu = preg_replace("/(.*)\/(.+)(-(.*)x(.*))\.jpg/",$altreplace, $altneu);
  
  if ($altneu == $alt){
   $alt = $pinalt;
  }
  
  $newimageclass = "";
  if ($columns == '3') {
   if ($i <= 2) {
    $newimageclass = "firstrowimage lazyload"; 
   } else {
    $newimageclass = "lazyload";
   }
   $tmp = '<img src="'. $url .'" alt="'. $alt .'" class="'. $newimageclass .'"/>';
   $srcset = wr2x_picture_rewrite($tmp); 
   $addsrc = add_attributes($srcset, $url);
   $script = add_data_srcset($addsrc);
   $items .= $script;
   $columnscount = "threecolumns";
  } else if ($columns == '2') {
   if ($i <= 1) {
    $newimageclass = "firstrowimage lazyload"; 
   } else {
    $newimageclass = "lazyload";
   }
   $tmp = '<img src="'. $url .'" alt="'. $alt .'" class="'. $newimageclass .'"/>';
   $srcset = wr2x_picture_rewrite($tmp); 
   $addsrc = add_attributes($srcset, $url);
   $script = add_data_srcset($addsrc);
   $items .= $script;
   $columnscount = "twocolumns";
  } else {
   // 1 column
   if ($i == 0) {
    $newimageclass = "firstrowimage lazyload"; 
   } else {
    $newimageclass = "lazyload";
   }
   $tmp = '<img src="'. $url .'" alt="'. $alt .'" class="'. $newimageclass .'"/>';
   $srcset = wr2x_picture_rewrite($tmp); 
   $addsrc = add_attributes($srcset, $url);
   $script = add_data_srcset($addsrc);
   $items .= $script;
   $columnscount = "onecolumn";
  }
  $i++;
 }
 $output .= "<div class=\"{$columnscount}\">{$items}</div></div>\n";
 
  echo $output; //WORKS IN ANY CASE
  return $output; //WORKS UP TO ~60 ITEMS
}
add_filter('post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2);
```

Helper functions are:

```html
function add_data_srcset ($input) {
 $match = '/(srcset)/';
 $replace = 'data-$1';
 $output = preg_replace($match, $replace, $input);
 return $output;
}
function add_attributes($srcset, $url){
 $match = '/(<img)/';
 $replace = '$1 src=data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw== ';
 $output = preg_replace($match, $replace, $srcset);
 return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do? Do you want to display your gallery on a page?

I think you don't need to use a hook for this.

You can use the add_action to call a function in a template to display the images. Simply call  in your template if you are using a return in your function.

```
add_action('display_post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2);
```

Or you can use a shortcode to display your gallery in a pagebuilder or the classic editor. Simply call [display_post_gallery] anywhere.

```
add_shortcode('display_post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery');
```

The next thing is, why do you want to use the a return? You are creating html in your $output, so if you want to display the gallery, only 'echo' works. A return will work if you echo the $output in your template.

Comment: I have a custom theme and call the gallery within the blogpost with a shortcode `[gallery columns={1,2,3} ids="..."]`. I thought the best/safe way to do this is to add the _post_gallery_ filter and specify my own gallery function, return it and let wordpress handle my output.

Comment: And btw.: I'd like to upload my images, click on create gallery and have the right shortcodes in place. To my knowledge, wordpress only inserts the [gallery] shortcode?

Comment: And that is why i use the return [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Notes]

Comment: You are creating your own HTML for the gallery, so as i said, create your own shortcode and echo the output, this should work fine. You can also pass your ID's via shortcode like this [display_post_gallery id="1,2,3"].

Comment: Thanks sodub! The problem with this solution is, that i'd like to use the build in uploader / gallery function, which generates a [gallery] shortcode. Is there any way to modify the build in gallery function to generate a different shortcode like [display_post_gallery]?

Comment: Your add_filter('post_gallery', 'my_post_gallery', 10, 2); only works if the hook exists. If your gallery function is defined in your parent theme, you can overwrite this function in the functions.php of your child theme by using this code: 
if ( ! function_exists ( 'my_function' ) ) {
    function my_function() {
        // Contents of your function here.
    }
}

Comment: The Hook exists (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_gallery/, i can see it in the media.php@core as well). My my_post_gallery is working up to approx. 60 images in one post. So there must be another problem. My custom theme is the one and only, there is no parent, so no chance to overwrite something?! (Btw.: Thanks for your help!)